# How do i send an email from localhost to my gmail

Tags: php

im using wamp and i want to test out an email function from a tutorial on youtube but it wont send and i got all the code correct and it sent the message your email has been sent. i even changed the php.ini file 
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com 
sendmail_from = philipnagel511@gmail.com 
any suggestions

if u can could u write me out an email function here is mine 
this is for a forgot password thing i am doing im trying to email the user their new password

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
?>
    <p>Thanks, we've emailed you.</p>
<?php
} else {
$mode_allowed = array('email', 'password');
if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'], $mode_allowed) === true) {
    if (isset($_POST['email']) === true && empty($_POST['email']) === false) {
        if (user_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            recover($_GET['mode'], $_POST['email']);
            header('Location: recover.php?success');
            exit();
        } else {
            echo '<p>Ooops, we couldn\'t find that email address</p>';
        }
    }
?>

function recover($mode, $email) {
    $mode    = sanitize($mode);
    $email   = sanitize($email);

    $user_data = user_data(user_id_from_email($email),'user_id', 'first_name', 'username');

    if ($mode == 'username') {
        email($email, 'Your username', "Hello " . $user_data['first_name'] . ",\n\nYour username is: ". $user_data['username'] . "\n\n-phpacademy");
    } else if ($mode == 'password') {
        $generated_password = substr(md5(rand(999, 999999)), 0, 8);
        change_password($user_data['user_id'], $generated_password);
        email($email, 'Your password recovery', "Hello " . $user_data['first_name'] . ",\n\nYour pasword is: ". $generated_password . "\n\n-phpacademy");
    }
}

function email($to, $subject, $body, $headers) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

Comment: If you simply want to test that the e-mail is sent from your code, you can always use tools like [DevNullSMTP](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtp.jsp) for sending e-mails on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Followed [this guide](http://www.projectpier.org/node/817) it will help you through.
Make sure you do everything there except using projectpier , you dont need it. You'll be using Php to send mail.

Sample Php Code:

```
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        echo "Mail successfully sent with given data"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "Mail sending failed! Please make sure all data is correct and you are connected to the internet";
    }
```

Make sure you set up all the variables correctly

Answer (score 0):

As far the sending of email is concerned, I would suggest to use PHPMAILER. You can get the same at [phpmailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

```
function send_email($recipient, $sender_email,$sender_name, $subject, $message){ 
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail   = new PHPMailer();
$body   = $message;
$mail->Host         =  'smtp.googlemail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth     =  true;
$mail->Username     =  'your gmail id';
$mail->Password     =  'your gmail password';
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->FromName     = $sender_name;
$mail->Port         = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'ssl';
$mail->From         = $sender_email;
$mail->Subject      = $subject;
$mail->AltBody      = strip_tags($message);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($recipient);


if ( ! $mail->Send())
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

}

I guess it will solve your problem.. 
Also, I would suggest you to follow the approach to identify the problem first. First of all check whether your mail function is working properly or not, just by passing hard coded values. Once you are confirmed with the same then pass the values through your form/code and check again what is the issue.